# AngularJS and JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I am trying to arrange the existed JSON Array following as below by using AngularJS filter such as $filter, but it is failing.

```
 {
        {       
            name: "name 1",         
            label: "A",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 2",         
            label: "A",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 3",         
            label: "B",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 4",         
            label: "B",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 5",         
            label: "B",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 6",         
            label: "C",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 7",         
            label: "C",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 8",         
            label: "C",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 9",         
            label: "D",     
        }
    }
```

What I want is to arrange this array to new one following as below.

```
{
    "A" : { 
        {       
            name: "name 1",         
            label: "A",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 2",         
            label: "A",     
        },
    },
    "B" : {
        {       
            name: "name 3",         
            label: "B",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 4",         
            label: "B",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 5",         
            label: "B",     
        },
    },
    "C" : {
        {       
            name: "name 6",         
            label: "C",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 7",         
            label: "C",     
        },
        {       
            name: "name 8",         
            label: "C",     
        },
    },
    "D" : {
        {       
            name: "name 9",         
            label: "D",
        }
    }   
}
```

How can I get the new array using angularJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy), you could utilise `_.groupBy` function for this:

```
var grouppedArray = _.groupBy(myArray, function(i){
  return i.label;
})
```

To extract only labels you could smth like this

```
var uniqueLables = [];
angular.forEach(myArray, function(obj){
  if(uniqueLables.indexOf(obj.label) == -1) uniqueLables.push(obj.label)
})
```

Comment: Thank you. one more help. How can I get only "A", "B", "C" without any children values?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   var result = {}
   angular.forEach(jsonData, function(obj){
       if(!result.hasOwnProperty(obj.label) result[obj.label] = []
       result[obj.label].push(obj)
   })

   console.log(result)
```